# Número automático para formulário

Tags: html

Eu queria por um numero automático após preencher um formulário ou  seja imagine que eu vou  preencher o meu formulário aquilo tem  que dizer Reserva nº1/2018 depois quando  outra pessoa for preencher outro  formulário aquilo tem  que dizer Reserva nº2/2018. Não sei se deu para entender.Obrigado a todos que me puderem ajudar.

O meu html:

Reserva Nº/2018

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            Dia:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="dia" type="date"  required />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Pessoas:
        </td>
            <td>
             <input name="pessoas"  type="number"  MAX="14" required />
            </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Hora:
        </td>
            <td>
            <select name="hora"type="text" required >
                <option value="0"></option>
                <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
                <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
                <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
                <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
                <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
                <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
                <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
                <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
                <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
                <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
                <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
                <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
                <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
                <option value="23:00">23:00</option>


            </select>
            </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
            Nome:
        </td>
            <td>
                <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" required />
            </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td>
            Numero:
        </td>
            <td>
                <input name="numero" type="number" required" />
            </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
            E-mail:
        </td>
            <td>
                 <input name= "email" type="text" required />
            </td>
    </tr>


                        <tr>
        <td>
        Mesa:
        </td>
            <td>
                <input name="mesa" type="Number" value="Reservar" max="11" required />
            </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>    
        </td>
            <td>
            <div class="butoesdelembrar">
              <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px font-size:60;"> Receber informação de eventos futuros?<br>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Promoções e atualizações deste restaurante<br>
```

Comment: Penso que precisas de guardar cada registo na base de dados, de forma a teres um número sequencial de registos. Em html puro, penso que não consegues, porque sempre que carregas a página, ele volta ao número inicial.

Comment: então  e se eu  pusesse o  id visivel ou seja quando a pessoas faz a reserva vai  conseguir ver que é o id 1 percebe?

Comment: Não precisas de por o Id visível, apenas se quiseres... o problema no código é que cada registo que fizeres, o Id vai ser sempre igual. Estás a guardar numa base de dados?

Comment: ainda não  mas um amigo  meu  disse me que isso dava para fazer com  javascpirt mas eu procurei e não econtrei

Comment: Sinceramente, quase de certeza que não dá para fazer isso em JavaScript, porque não tens maneira de guardar o valor...

Comment: tenho  que usar php  então?

Comment: Sim, convém... Fazes insert na BD sempre que um registo é criado, e a partir daí tens o ID. Se quiseres, cria mais um campo que diga "idregisto" de forma a poderes manusear o ID e incrementar o i/2018 (1/2018,2/2018,3/2018...)

Comment: @sintra, o `Javascript` roda no navegador do usuário, logo não vais ter como controlar a sequencia numérica para todos usuários, cada usuário vai começar em "1". Para que isso funcione, precisa centralizar o código, e isso tem de ser feito no lado *server*, não importa a linguagem. Imagina que você está no número "10", o próximo por certeza será "11", mas e se outro usuário, em outro navegador tentar salvar o formulário primeiro e já usou "11"? Percebe porque o servidor precisa controlar isso?

Comment: Mas é possível fazer isso com JavaScript + [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=pt-br), mas talvez seja mais fácil com PHP + SQL. De uma olhada e veja qual prefere

Comment: kk obrigado a todos que me deram dicas.